# How to track a custom event on google Analytics

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-analytics

How to track a custom event on Google Analytics. I have used this code alone:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-42651041-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Popup','Click','Step1']); //on button click
```

Is there any extra code need to be added? for tracking, on every event?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need any other code, just event tracking code is enough. Once you installed google analytics , please the event tracking code in your button “OnClick” event.

For more information , https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Sample code from my site (I am tracking traffic to my social media sites in button OnClick event)

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/isharashehan" target="_blank" title="LinkedIn" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'LinksToSocialMedia', 'SM_Button_Click','LinkedIn']);"> # </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get a [tracking snippet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking) from Google Analytics. Only after you put that code into your header must you insert your [event tracking code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#SettingUpEventTracking).
Note that on that page it states that:

> Once event tracking has been **set up** and working on your site for **a
>   day**, go to the Content section of the reports and view Event Tracking

You're welcome :)